# How can I access subclass attribute through passing its superclass as parameter of a method

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a method that accepts two classes `Pokemon` as its parameters because it could be whatever pokemon battling, but if I try to catch the name of the subclass, such as `Totodile`, the superclass's name attribute is printed

in Pokemon.java:

```
abstract  public class Pokemon {
        private String name="POKEMON";
   
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
    }
```

in Totodile.java :

```
public class Totodile extends Pokemon {
    String name = "Totodile";
}
```

in Geodude.java :

```
public class Totodile extends Pokemon {
    String name = "Geodude";
}
```

in Battle.java :

```
public class Battle {
   public void initiateBattle(Pokemon pokemon1,Pokemon pokemon2){
        System.out.println(pokemon1.getName()+ " is battling against " + pokemon2.getName());  
    }

}
```

in App.java:

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Geodude geodude = new Geodude();
    Totodile totodile = new Totodile();
    Battle battle = new Battle();
    battle.initiateBattle(totodile, geodude);
  }
}
```

The output is `"POKEMON is battling against POKEMON"`

, but how could I get `"Totodile is battling against Geodude"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "override" a field. When you write:

```
class Foo {
  String name;
}
```

you are **always declaring a new field**. If your superclass *also* has a field with the same name, okay. Now your Totodile class has **2** fields, **both** named `name`, one of which has value `POKEMON`, the other has value `Totodile`.

Which one do you get when you write `myPokemon.name`? Depends on the compile-time type of `myPokemon` (the variable, *not* the object it is pointing at!) - and given that it is `Pokemon` in your code, you get the Pokemon version of the `name` field.

This notion that you have 2 fields with identical names is called 'shadowing'.

**Shadowing is a mistake; do not do it unless you really, *really* know what you are doing**.

The solution is therefore quite simple: Don't define a field named `name` in the Totodile class. Instead, set the value of the `name` field (which you inherited, so the Totodile class has that name field already, no need to make a second field with the same name and confuse things):

```
class Totodile {
  { name = "Totodile"; }
}
```

This somewhat weird syntax creates an instance initializer, as you need to stuff your code somewhere (you can't just start putting statements straight into a class, you need to brace em up). This is a tad odd, the more usual design is instead something like this:

```
abstract class Pokemon {
  private final String name;

  public Pokemon(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}

class Totodile extends Pokemon {
  public Totodile() {
    super("Totodile");
  }
}
```

This is what most java programmers do:

- It forces subclasses of Pokemon to actually set the name properly. That default 'POKEMON' value is weird and no longer needed in the above strategy.
- It avoids exotic code constructs to make it work. Constructors and abstract classes tend to be a lot more familiar to your average java coder than instance initializers.
- Adds `final` in the appropriate places.